# JSF 2 datatable : add cell values

Tags: jsf-2

I am working with JSF 2 data table which has 5 rows and 5 columns. When a user enters values into a column (for example column5), I need to add the values of first 4 cells (row1col5 + row2col5 + row3col5 + row4col5) and update the new value in the cell row5col5 dynamically.
Is this possible? by using valueChangeListener or f:ajax?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Su

Comment: The functional requirement is not clear. Should this only happen for the last row? Or should this happen for all rows, for the values of all previous rows?

Comment: BalusC, This should happen for only row5col5. Users enter the input only in first four cells of a column and expect the output (Sum of all values) in the last cell of the same column. Hope its clear.

Comment: Okay, thus only for the **last row**? And not explicitly "5th row"?

Comment: Yes BalusC. Is this possible?